# Pyspark data frame Converting false and true to 0 and 1

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame in Pyspark

```
df.show()


+-----+-----+
|test1|test2|
+-----+-----+
|false| true|
| true| true|
| true|false|
|false| true|
|false|false|
|false|false|
|false|false|
| true| true|
|false|false|
+-----+-----+
```

I want to convert all the `false` values in data frame to `0` and `true to 1`.

I am doing like below

```
df1 = df.withColumn('test1', F.when(df.test1 == 'false', 0).otherwise(1)).withColumn('test2', F.when(df.test2 == 'false', 0).otherwise(1))
```

I got my result. But I think there might be a better way to do this.

Comment: How about `int(df.test1)`, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `CASE ... WHEN` (`when(...).otherwise(...)`) is unnecessarily verbose. Instead you can just `cast` to integer:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df.select([col(c).cast("integer") for c ["test1", "test2"]])
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that the datatypes of the two columns (`test1`, `test2`) are Boolean. You can try the below mentioned suggestion:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn( "test1" , F.when( F.col("test1") , F.lit(1) ).otherwise(0) ).withColumn( "test2" , F.when( F.col("test2") , F.lit(1) ).otherwise(0) )
```

The columns `"test1"` and `"test2"` are Boolean in nature. So, you do not need to equate them using `==True` (or `==False`).

The use of Pyspark functions makes this route faster (and more scalable) as compared to approaches which use udfs (user defined functions).

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid the multiple `withColumn` especially when you have a lot of columns could be to use `functools.reduce` and you only use `withColumn` once here:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from functools import reduce

cols = ['test1', 'test2']
reduce(lambda df, c: df.withColumn(c, F.when(df[c] == 'false', 0).otherwise(1)), cols, df).show()
+-----+-----+
|test1|test2|
+-----+-----+
|    1|    0|
|    0|    1|
+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this help to do it in a clear way and for other cases too:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions 
import  col from pyspark.sql.types 
import IntegerType 

def fromBooleanToInt(s):
    """
    This is just a simple python function to move boolean to integers.
    
    >>> fromBooleanToInt(None)
    >>> fromBooleanToInt(True)
    1
    >>> fromBooleanToInt(False)
    1
    """
    if s == True:
        return 1
    elif s==False:
        return 0
    else:
        return None
```

This is to create a simple dataframe to test

```
df_with_doubles = spark.createDataFrame([(True, False), (None,True)], ['A', 'B']) 
df_with_doubles.show()
+----+-----+
|   A|    B|
+----+-----+
|true|false|
|null| true|
+----+-----+
```

This is to define the udf

```
fromBooleanToInt_udf = F.udf(lambda x: fromBooleanToInt(x), IntegerType())
```

Now let do the casting/transformation:

```
column_to_change = 'A' 
df_with_doubles_ = df_with_doubles.withColumn(column_to_change,fromBooleanToInt_udf(df_with_doubles[column_to_change])) 
df_with_doubles_.show()
+----+-----+
|   A|    B|
+----+-----+
|   1|false|
|null| true|
+----+-----+
```

Answer (score -1):

For Scala Users :

```
df.withColumn('new', col("test1").isNotNull.cast(IntegerType))
```

I Hope it helps.